# CLS-Compliant method to dynamically free marshal'd memory for nested IntPtr(s) in generic struct in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, marshalling, intptr

I have seen some examples that use reflection to identify fields of `structs`, and set their value, etc.

Is there a way to identify a field of a `struct` as an `IntPtr` within a helper function which frees the `marshal'd` memory which is also CLS-compliant?

Ex:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SMyStruct
{
    public IntPtr pMyPtr;
}

public void myFunc()
{
    SMyStruct Foo = new SMyStruct();
    Foo.pMyPtr    = Marshal.AllochGlobal(some amount of memory);

    // Do something with Foo

    DeAllocateStructMemory<SMyStruct>(ref Foo);  // <-- My helper function that accepts a struct and attempts to free any IntPtrs within the structure
}

// Helper function pseudo code
public void DeAllocateStructMemory<T>(ref T sSomeStruct)
{
    foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance  |
                                              BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                              BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (field.FieldType == typeof(IntPtr))
        {
             var pMyData  = field.GetValue(sSomeStruct);
             IntPtr myPtr = (IntPtr) pMyData;
             FreeMemory(ref myPtr);

             // Set the IntPtr member to zero 
             // NOTE: NOT CLS Compliant
             field.SetValueDirect(__makeref(sSomeStruct), IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}

public void FreeMemory(ref IntPtr pMem)
{
    if (pMem != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMem);
        pMem = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #1** Believe I've found how to deallocate the memory, but still cannot set the `struct` member/field to `IntPtr.Zero` after the memory is freed.

**UPDATE #2** Figured out how to set the `IntPtr` member of the struct, although it is through a method that is not CLS-Compliant. I am only using this application in Windows so I don't think its an issue, but open to suggestions if anyone knows of a better method.

Comment: It is not very clear why you can't use FieldInfo.FieldType to detect the IntPtr.  It is rather a bad idea to hide this, exactly who owns the pointer and is responsible for releasing the memory is always very murky.  You never want to hide a dangling pointer bug, they are entirely too difficult to debug.  The release call should be loud, easy to find back and heavily commented..

Comment: Its not necessarily that I'm hiding pointers, I was just hoping to have a single function to handle freeing of memory for any structure(s) with a nested IntPtr member. I can use FieldType to detect it, but I'm not sure how to then pass that member to a helper function

Comment: I'm working with a C++ DLL with nested structure pointers, so in my C# code I have the same data structure, I set up the required memory, pass to C++, then have to drill all the way in and start freeing the memory allocated for the IntPtrs starting at the inner-most level, just wanted to see if there was a generic way to locate every IntPtr member in an object and pass it to a handler function

Comment: It isn't very clear what "helper function" you might be talking about, you didn't write one.  You need to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal(), that's all.  Passing nested structures to C++ code is *exactly* the scary dangling pointer bug scenario btw, you step in deep doggie doo if the C++ code copied the structure, or a pointer inside the structure, and keeps using it.  You can't see the memory corruption that causes until much later.

Comment: I updated my question with some of the helper logic, and yes I agree the situation is not Ideal, but the data used by the C++ DLL is copied locally so the pointers from the C# side only need to exist to pass data, not be accessed afterwards

Comment: Just to clarify futher: Pointers point to arrays, arrays are copied locally by C++ with properly allocated memory, not just copying the pointers to be accessed at a later time